# HTML button becomes square after background color is set on Chrome for Mac

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome, button

on Chrome for Mac, why the buttons become square after background color is set (normally it is rounded)?

```
<html>
<body>
  <input type="button" id="bt1" value="Click me!" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='red;'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='transparent';">
</body>
</html>
```

The web page when the mouse has not been over the button:

[image]

The web page when the mouse is over the button:

[image]

The web page after the mouse was over the button:

[image]

How to set the background without making the button square?

Thanks.

Comment: Also occurs on Firefox Android Beta (2022)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebKit/Blink draws buttons as "-webkit-appearance:push-button", which draws buttons with the native API (Cocoa in this case). However the native API doesn't support arbitrary background colors.  So WebKit/Blink automatically removes "-webkit-appearance:push-button" internally and falls back to poor CSS drawing if a web author specifies some CSS properties such as background-color.

You can't change background color with the native button appearance.

Answer (score 1):

I offer you to set your own Radius.
In this way, the design of your button would be stable on every browsers and you won't face this problem again.

Use this style to works on every browsers.

```
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-khtml-border-radius: 3px;    
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
```

*Be successful*

Comment: Your code can make the button rounded. However, it does not look like the same as the original one. In addition, I wonder that why we change only the background color but the border was also influenced?

Answer (score 1):

you have to customized it using css. like this

```
input#bt1{border-radius:3px; 
-moz-border-radius:3px; 
-webkit-border-radius:3px; border:none;}

input#bt1:hover{background:#ff0000; 
color:#fff}
```

By using this you have set your markup like this

```
<html>
<body>
  <input type="button" id="bt1" value="Click me!">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was only able to match the style on 10.11 with radius of 5px, and padding 2px 8px 3px (top left/right bottom).

Answer (score 0):

You are using default button. So, you can't able to change that one. And the latest version of chrome using rounded button.

Try this css for your Button to keep rounded:

```
background: #fff;
border-radius: 5px;
```

Comment: Your code can make the button rounded. However, it does not look like the same as the original one. In addition, I wonder that why I changed only the background color but the border was also influenced?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your own design using css for button... may be it is default theme..

Answer (score 0):

For round corner you need to add css

```
<style>
  input{ background:#ccc; border-radius:6px;  border:1px solid #ccc; }
  input:hover{background:red;}
 </style>
```

Comment: Your code can make the button rounded. However, I wonder that why iin my code, I changed only the background color but the border was also influenced?